# Split character string multiple times every two characters

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyr

I have a character column in my dataframe that looks like

```
df<-
  data.frame(a=c("AaBbCC","AABBCC","AAbbCC"))#df
       a
1 AaBbCC
2 AABBCC
3 AAbbCC
```

I would like to split this column every two characters. So in this case I would like to obtain three columns named `VA,VB,VC`.
I tried

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df<-
  data.frame(a=c("AaBbCC","AABBCC","AAbbCC"))%>%
  separate(a,c(paste("V",LETTERS[1:3],sep="")),sep=c(2,2))
 VA VB   VC
1 Aa    BbCC
2 AA    BBCC
3 AA    bbCC
```

but this is not the desired result. I like to have the result that is now in `VC` split into `VB` (all letter B) and `VC` (all letter C)How do I get R to split every two characters. The length of the string in the column is always the same for every row (6 in this example).
I will have strings that are of length >10.

Comment: i dont have a tidyr solution `strsplit(c("AaBbCC","AABBCC","AAbbCC"), '(?<=..)', perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were actually quite close. You need to specify the separator-positions as `sep = c(2,4)` instead of `sep = c(2,2)`:

```
df <- separate(df, a, c(paste0("V",LETTERS[1:3])), sep = c(2,4))
```

you get:

> ```
> > df
>   VA VB VC
> 1 Aa Bb CC
> 2 AA BB CC
> 3 AA bb CC
> ```

---

In base R you could do (borrowing from @rawr's comment):

```
l <- ave(as.character(df$a), FUN = function(x) strsplit(x, '(?<=..)', perl = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', l))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>   X1 X2 X3
> 1 Aa Bb CC
> 2 AA BB CC
> 3 AA bb CC
> ```

Comment: Havent thought of c(2,4). I was assuming that it starts counting from 0 after every separation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

We could do this with `base R`

```
read.csv(text=gsub('(..)(?!$)', '\\1,', df$a, 
    perl=TRUE),col.names=paste0("V", LETTERS[1:3]), header=FALSE)
#  VA VB VC
#1 Aa Bb CC
#2 AA BB CC
#3 AA bb CC
```

If we are reading directly from the file, another option is `read.fwf`

```
read.fwf(file="yourfile.txt", widths=c(2,2,2), skip=1)
```