# Put space every two characters in text string

Tags: text, replace, sublimetext

Given the following string:

```
6e000000b0040000044250534bb4f6fd02d6dc5bc0790c2fde3166a14146009c8684a4624
```

Which is a representation of a Byte array, every two characters represent a Byte.

I would like to put a space between each Byte using Sublime Text, something like:

```
6e 00 00 00 b0 04 00 00 04 42 50
```

Does Sublime Text help me on that issue?

As a bonus I would like to split into lines and add 0x before each Byte.

I found a similar question but that's not related no Sublime Text, [Split character string multiple times every two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695136/split-character-string-multiple-times-every-two-characters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Find->Replace... and enable regular expressions.

Replace: `(.{2})`

With: `$1SPACE`

Where SPACE is a space.

Answer (score 2):

To split it onto separate lines and add `0x` before each byte do this:

Find `(.{2})`

Replace with: `0x\1\n`